# prefect.io kubernetes agent and task execution

Tags: prefect

While reading [kubernetes agent documentation](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/agents/kubernetes.html#requirements), I am getting confused with below line

"*Configure a flow-run to run as a Kubernetes Job.*"

Does it mean that the process which is incharge of submitting flow and communication with api server will run as kubernetes job?

On the other side, the use case which I am trying to solve is

1. Setup backend server
2. Execute a flow composed of 2 tasks
3. if k8s infra available the tasks should be executed as kubernetes jobs
4. if docker only infra available, the tasks should be executed as docker containers.

Can somebody suggest me, how to solve above scenario in prefect.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly right. When you use KubernetesAgent, Prefect deploys your flow runs as Kubernetes jobs.

For #1 - you can do that in your agent YAML file as follows:

```yaml
        env:
        - name: PREFECT__CLOUD__AGENT__AUTH_TOKEN
          value: ''
        - name: PREFECT__CLOUD__API
          value: "http://some_ip:4200/graphql" # paste your GraphQL Server endpoint here
        - name: PREFECT__BACKEND
          value: server
```

#2 - write your flow

#3 and #4 - this is more challenging to do in Prefect, as there is currently no load balancing mechanism aware of your infrastructure. There are some hacky solutions that you may try, but there is no first-class way to handle this in Prefect.

One hack would be: you build a parent flow that checks your infrastructure resources and depending on the outcome, it spins up your flow run with either DockerRun or KubernetesRun run config.

```py
from prefect import Flow, task, case
from prefect.tasks.prefect import create_flow_run, wait_for_flow_run
from prefect.run_configs import DockerRun, KubernetesRun


@task
def check_the_infrastructure():
    return "kubernetes"


with Flow("parent_flow") as flow:
    infra = check_the_infrastructure()
    with case(infra, "kubernetes"):
        child_flow_run_id = create_flow_run(
            flow_name="child_flow_name", run_config=KubernetesRun()
        )
        k8_child_flowrunview = wait_for_flow_run(
            child_flow_run_id, raise_final_state=True, stream_logs=True
        )
    with case(infra, "docker"):
        child_flow_run_id = create_flow_run(
            flow_name="child_flow_name", run_config=DockerRun()
        )
        docker_child_flowrunview = wait_for_flow_run(
            child_flow_run_id, raise_final_state=True, stream_logs=True
        )
```

But note that this would require you to have 2 agents: Kubernetes agent and Docker agent running at all times

Comment: Thanks Anna Geller for the detailed response. Its helpful. However one thing which I am still trying to understand is how we can specify tasks with in child flow to execute as container. Assuming task 1 is written in java and task 2 in python and both have their own images.
I am referring the suggestion mentioned here
https://docs.prefect.io/core/faq.html#how-can-i-include-non-python-tasks-in-a-prefect-flow

Comment: I see, in that case, you may try using [Docker](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/tasks/docker.html#docker-tasks) and [Kubernetes tasks](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/tasks/kubernetes.html#kubernetes-tasks) for non-python containers such as a Java application.

Comment: Thanks Anna for pointing me to the docs. It helps. However I really wish if prefect had some examples in github. Currently it requires to understand the documentation thoroughly to try out use cases quickly for exploration purposes.   I will mark your answer as accept. thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback and I totally agree :) When I was getting started with Prefect, I also wished there were more code examples. To make it easier to find and share relevant examples, we've recently launched a [Discourse forum](http://discourse.prefect.io/) - a very similar question to your use case came up [here for example](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/can-i-run-a-flow-of-flows-that-triggers-each-child-flow-on-a-different-machine/180)